# pyQT5 - missing field update when inserting row in a SQLite table using QdataWidget mapper

Tags: sqlite, pyqt5

I have a problem using QDataWidgetMapper and QSQLTableModel to insert a row in a SQLlite table: I have a SQlite table with QSQLTableModel and QDataWidgetMapper set to such model.
I set-up a filter to the model to select only specific rows. The problem is when I insert a new row, only the value of few fields is updated in the SQLite table, while all others entered in the form are not present. Below is the code, along with the .ui file, the screenshot of the SQLite table structure, the screenshot of the input form with data input and the screenshot of the table record after the input. Thanks for any suggestion

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlRelation, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView,QWidget,QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QDialog, QMenu, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QDataWidgetMapper
from connect_SQLITE import Database
from gestione_fase_testUi import Ui_f_gestioneFaseTest

class Fase(QWidget, Ui_f_gestioneFaseTest):
    def __init__(self, nome_prev=None, num_prev=None, rev_prev=None, fase=None, ie=None):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.dataIns=QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        self.dataMod=QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()

        self.num_prev='1'      
        self.rev_prev='1'
        self.fase=fase
        self.interna_esterna=ie 

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.assegnazione_modello_dati()
        self.assegnazione_mapper()    
       
        self.pbInsFase.setEnabled(False) 
        self.pbInsFase.setVisible(False)       
        self.pbCancFase.setEnabled(False)
        self.pbModFase.setEnabled(False)
        self.pbNuovaFase.setEnabled(True)   
      
        self.pbNuovaFase.clicked.connect(self.nuova_fase)
        self.pbInsFase.clicked.connect(self.inserimento_fase) 
        self.pbModFase.clicked.connect(self.modifica_fase) 
        self.pbCancFase.clicked.connect(self.cancellazione_fase) 
          
        self.pbFirst.clicked.connect(self.mapperFasiDett.toFirst)
        self.pbLast.clicked.connect(self.mapperFasiDett.toLast)
        self.pbPrevious.clicked.connect(self.mapperFasiDett.toPrevious)
        self.pbNext.clicked.connect(self.mapperFasiDett.toNext)     
           
    def assegnazione_modello_dati(self):
        self.modelFasiDett = QSqlTableModel()
        self.modelFasiDett.setTable("tb_FasiTest1")
        filtro=""
        
        if not self.num_prev:
           self.modelFasiDett.setFilter("")
        elif not self.fase:
           filtro = "codicePreventivo = "+"'"+self.num_prev+"'" + " AND revisionePreventivo = " + "'" + self.rev_prev + "'"
           self.modelFasiDett.setFilter(filtro)
        else:
           filtro = "codicePreventivo = "+"'"+self.num_prev+"'" + " AND revisionePreventivo = " + "'" + self.rev_prev + "'" + " AND nomeFase = " + "'" + self.fase + "'" 
           self.modelFasiDett.setFilter(filtro)
   
    def assegnazione_mapper(self):  
             
        self.mapperFasiDett = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapperFasiDett.setSubmitPolicy(self.mapperFasiDett.ManualSubmit)
        self.mapperFasiDett.setModel(self.modelFasiDett)

        self.lbNomePrev.setVisible(False)
        self.lE_nomePrev.setVisible(False)

        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.lE_codPrev, 0)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.lE_revPrev, 1)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.lE_fase, 2)  
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_Qta, 3)     
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_barraU, 4)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_setupH, 5)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_setupM, 6)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_cicloS, 7)  
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_cicloM, 8)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_percScarto, 9)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.SB_PercEff, 10)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.dataIns, 11)
        self.mapperFasiDett.addMapping(self.dataMod, 12)     
            
        self.mapperFasiDett.toFirst()
        iModel=self.mapperFasiDett.currentIndex() 

        if not self.lE_codPrev.text():
           self.lE_codPrev.setText(self.num_prev)
        if not self.lE_revPrev.text():   
           self.lE_revPrev.setText(self.rev_prev) 

    def nuova_fase(self):
   
      self.rows=self.modelFasiDett.rowCount()
     
      self.pbInsFase.setEnabled(True) 
      self.pbInsFase.setVisible(True) 
      self.pbModFase.setEnabled(False) 
      self.pbCancFase.setEnabled(False)

    def inserimento_fase(self):
   
       self.dataIns.setDateTime(datetime.now())
       self.dataMod.setDateTime(datetime.now())

       rows=self.modelFasiDett.rowCount()
       self.modelFasiDett.insertRows(rows, 1)
  
       self.mapperFasiDett.toLast()
       self.mapperFasiDett.submit()

    def modifica_fase(self):
        print("modifica")

    def cancellazione_fase(self):
        print("cancella")    
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Fase()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

----- .ui file -----

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_f_gestioneFaseTest(object):
    def setupUi(self, f_gestioneFaseTest):
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setObjectName("f_gestioneFaseTest")
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.resize(557, 433)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.lbDescFase = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lbDescFase.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lbDescFase.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lbDescFase.setObjectName("lbDescFase")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbDescFase)
        self.lE_fase = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lE_fase.setObjectName("lE_fase")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lE_fase)
        self.lbQta = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbQta.setObjectName("lbQta")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbQta)
        self.SB_Qta = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_Qta.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_Qta.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_Qta.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        self.SB_Qta.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_Qta.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_Qta.setMaximum(999999)
        self.SB_Qta.setObjectName("SB_Qta")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_Qta)
        self.lbBarraU = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbBarraU.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbBarraU.setObjectName("lbBarraU")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbBarraU)
        self.SB_barraU = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_barraU.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_barraU.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_barraU.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_barraU.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_barraU.setMaximum(99999)
        self.SB_barraU.setObjectName("SB_barraU")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_barraU)
        self.lbSetupH = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbSetupH.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbSetupH.setObjectName("lbSetupH")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbSetupH)
        self.SB_setupH = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_setupH.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_setupH.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_setupH.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_setupH.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_setupH.setObjectName("SB_setupH")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_setupH)
        self.lbSetupM = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbSetupM.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbSetupM.setObjectName("lbSetupM")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbSetupM)
        self.SB_setupM = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.SB_setupM.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_setupM.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_setupM.setObjectName("SB_setupM")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_setupM)
        self.lbCicloS = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbCicloS.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbCicloS.setObjectName("lbCicloS")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbCicloS)
        self.SB_cicloS = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_cicloS.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_cicloS.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_cicloS.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_cicloS.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_cicloS.setMaximum(99999)
        self.SB_cicloS.setObjectName("SB_cicloS")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_cicloS)
        self.lbCicloM = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbCicloM.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbCicloM.setObjectName("lbCicloM")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbCicloM)
        self.SB_cicloM = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.SB_cicloM.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_cicloM.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_cicloM.setObjectName("SB_cicloM")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_cicloM)
        self.lbPerScarto = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbPerScarto.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbPerScarto.setObjectName("lbPerScarto")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbPerScarto)
        self.SB_percScarto = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_percScarto.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_percScarto.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_percScarto.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_percScarto.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_percScarto.setDecimals(4)
        self.SB_percScarto.setMaximum(99.9999)
        self.SB_percScarto.setObjectName("SB_percScarto")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_percScarto)
        self.lbPercEff = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbPercEff.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lbPercEff.setObjectName("lbPercEff")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lbPercEff)
        self.SB_PercEff = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.SB_PercEff.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.SB_PercEff.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.SB_PercEff.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.SB_PercEff.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.SB_PercEff.setDecimals(4)
        self.SB_PercEff.setMaximum(99.9999)
        self.SB_PercEff.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.SB_PercEff.setObjectName("SB_PercEff")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.SB_PercEff)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.lbNomePrev = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.lbNomePrev.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lbNomePrev.setObjectName("lbNomePrev")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lbNomePrev)
        self.lE_nomePrev = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lE_nomePrev.setFont(font)
        self.lE_nomePrev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(118, 214, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 38, 0);\n"
"")
        self.lE_nomePrev.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lE_nomePrev.setObjectName("lE_nomePrev")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lE_nomePrev)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lE_codPrev = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lE_codPrev.setFont(font)
        self.lE_codPrev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(118, 214, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 38, 0);\n"
"")
        self.lE_codPrev.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lE_codPrev.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lE_codPrev.setObjectName("lE_codPrev")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lE_codPrev)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lE_revPrev = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lE_revPrev.setFont(font)
        self.lE_revPrev.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(118, 214, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 38, 0);")
        self.lE_revPrev.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lE_revPrev.setObjectName("lE_revPrev")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lE_revPrev)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pbNuovaFase = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbNuovaFase.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pbNuovaFase.setObjectName("pbNuovaFase")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pbNuovaFase)
        self.pbInsFase = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbInsFase.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 144, 81);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pbInsFase.setObjectName("pbInsFase")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pbInsFase)
        self.pbModFase = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbModFase.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(215, 131, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pbModFase.setObjectName("pbModFase")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pbModFase)
        self.pbCancFase = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbCancFase.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 38, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pbCancFase.setObjectName("pbCancFase")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pbCancFase)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.pbFirst = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbFirst.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
        self.pbFirst.setObjectName("pbFirst")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pbFirst)
        self.pbLast = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbLast.setObjectName("pbLast")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pbLast)
        self.pbPrevious = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbPrevious.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
        self.pbPrevious.setObjectName("pbPrevious")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pbPrevious)
        self.pbNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        self.pbNext.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
        self.pbNext.setObjectName("pbNext")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pbNext)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lbNomeRisorsa = QtWidgets.QLabel(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lbNomeRisorsa.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lbNomeRisorsa.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lbNomeRisorsa.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.lbNomeRisorsa.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.lbNomeRisorsa.setText("")
        self.lbNomeRisorsa.setObjectName("lbNomeRisorsa")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lbNomeRisorsa, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(f_gestioneFaseTest)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_Qta, self.SB_barraU)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_barraU, self.SB_setupH)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_setupH, self.SB_setupM)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_setupM, self.SB_cicloS)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_cicloS, self.SB_cicloM)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_cicloM, self.SB_percScarto)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_percScarto, self.SB_PercEff)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.SB_PercEff, self.pbFirst)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.pbFirst, self.pbPrevious)
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setTabOrder(self.pbPrevious, self.pbNext)

    def retranslateUi(self, f_gestioneFaseTest):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        f_gestioneFaseTest.setWindowTitle(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Inserimento Riga Preventivo"))
        self.lbDescFase.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "descrizione Fase"))
        self.lbQta.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Quantità"))
        self.lbBarraU.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Barra utile"))
        self.lbSetupH.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Setup (h)"))
        self.lbSetupM.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Setup (min)"))
        self.lbCicloS.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Ciclo (s)"))
        self.lbCicloM.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Ciclo (min)"))
        self.lbPerScarto.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "% Scarto"))
        self.lbPercEff.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "% Efficienza"))
        self.lbNomePrev.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "nome preventivo"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "codice preventivo"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "revisione"))
        self.pbNuovaFase.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Nuova Fase"))
        self.pbInsFase.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Inserimento Fase"))
        self.pbModFase.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Modifica"))
        self.pbCancFase.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Cancellazione"))
        self.pbFirst.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Primo"))
        self.pbLast.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Ultimo"))
        self.pbPrevious.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Precedente"))
        self.pbNext.setText(_translate("f_gestioneFaseTest", "Successivo"))
```

[image: SQLite table structure]

[image: Input form]
[image: SQLite table record after input]

Comment: Sorry but with the above code is almost impossible to really help you. We don't know the table structure (most importantly, the field types), nor we could easily correlate the code (which has lots of obscure object names) with the fields in the UI and the table. I suggest you to create a basic [mre] with a simple table containing only a few fields that reflect the various types, ensure that you can still reproduce the issue and then update your post with that.

Comment: I've changed the example including table structure and .ui file and reducing the fields number. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but the example is still too extensive, and forces us to manually create the table. I sincerely doubt that you get inconsistent and unpredictable results with 12 fields. Please, take your time, craft a valid MRE that *has* to be *both* minimal *and* reproducible, which means that there should not be unknown imports, and the table is created entirely by its code. Sorry if I may sound annoying in these requests, but this is not a debugging service, we must be able to *easily* focus on the problem, not be distracted in recreating it even before having the chance to understand it.